# Creating git project with initial commit?

Tags: git, gitlab, commit, gerrit, git-commit

What is the difference between a git project with initial commit and with out initial commit in gerrit?

I have created project now users are facing issue with it.

Comment: This is a bit vague for someone to answer. What kind of issues are they facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A project initialized already with a commit can be cloned.

A project *without* any commits is only set up in the Git server (Gerrit, GitHub, probably Gitlab as well) but cannot be cloned, as no repository is initialized. Thus, this has to be done locally and pushed to the server (while creating the first branch, usually *master*, during that process).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you please share steps to create master branch n commit .